# Unexpected token ILLEGAL when using chrome, and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" however i can not for the life of me find why this is throwing errors, can anyone provide any pointers?

```js
var dont_confirm_leave = 0; //set dont_confirm_leave to 1 when you want the user to be able to leave withou confirmation
var leave_message = 'Any data you have filled in on this page will be lost...';

document.getElementsByClassName('NextBtn').onclick = function() {
  window.NextButton = true;
};
document.getElementById('BackBtn').onclick = function() {
  window.BackButton = true;
}​;

function goodbye(e) {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("id=website") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("id=channel") > -1) {
    dont_confirm_leave = 1;
  }

  if (!window.NextButton) {
    return dont_confirm_leave = 1;
  }

  if (!window.BackButton) {
    return dont_confirm_leave = 1;
  }

  if (dont_confirm_leave !== 1) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = leave_message;
    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    //return works for Chrome and Safari
    return leave_message;
  }
}
window.onbeforeunload = goodbye;
```

Comment: There's an invisible invalid character at the end of the second event handler

Comment: paste into a fiddle, and you'll see it -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zzzukrLr/**

Comment: what's more intriguing is why it got there?

Comment: That Fiddler link worked, i could not see that in Visual Studio! lol thanks so much for your help, now to test it again

Comment: Strangly its not working now :/ Its meant to pop up a msg when the user refreshes, or reloads the page, unless its a button click